# How to develop android apps on and old PC?

Tags: android

I have a 6 years old PC that i use for development, but I’m getting into android development and android studio eclipse.. does not work on my PC.
Is there another way to develop android apps without using java(I’ve js,html,Apache before but i can’t do a lit of things with it)
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: *without using java* -- Nope

Comment: actually it's --YES

Comment: Not native apps, no. You are welcome to use Xamarin or whatever else cross-platform tool.

Comment: I saw that google is making a framework to develop android apps in Dart

Comment: Yes, [they are](https://flutter.io/), but that is still in early development. You are better off with Xamarin or React Native.

Comment: yeah i think so thanks by the way

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plain old notepad editor and compile using the binaries included in the android sdk. Just as you can write Java in plain old text and compile from the command line. But at least here you can visit so many Thrift sites well known and pick up half way decent computers for a hundred bucks. spending a little money on a computer that can Run Studio or Eclipse will save you 3/4 The headaches and Time.